Creating Domains via CloudShell
Please, I ask for help from the community. I would like to know the detailed steps to publish new DNS records using Google Cloud Shell. What are the specific commands required to create and manage A, CNAME, MX, or TXT records, in addition to ensuring that network configurations and permissions are properly set to make the process secure and efficient?
